# How to select a random span from many spans javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of spans, they are set to display in-line block with a width and height of 60px, i want javascript to pick a random span from all of them and apply a color to it. I don't really even know where to begin with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post [**your current code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you are having issues with, accompanied by a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar), if required, to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: There are many examples of selecting a random element from an array. Since you can treat the result of `getElementsByTagName` as an array, any of those examples should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters,

```
var elts = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
```

if using jQuery:

```
elts = $('span')
```

so now `elts` contains all the `span`s in the document.

The tricky part is selecting a random element within. We have to use `Math.floor(Math.random() * elts.length)` to select a random index. This is an earful, so the explanation:

- `Math.random()` returns a random from [0,1).
- `elts.length` is the length of the array. We multiply this by `Math.random()` to get a random array index from 0 to `elts.length` exclusive.
- `Math.floor()` rounds down, so that we don't get an out of bounds exception.

Put it all together:

```
var myRandomSpan = elts[Math.floor(Math.random() * elts.length)]
```

and there you have it. You can do what you please with `myRandomSpan`.

Comment: Thank you this works really well. Do you know if there is a way to do this by id if not that's okay, thank you though.

Comment: By ID? HTML specifies that IDs are unique per element, so you cannot have 2 `span`s (or any 2 elements) having the same ID. Wouldn't make sense to select a random SPAN from 1 SPANs.

Answer (score 0):

You say you don't know where to begin. Well, with a little thought it becomes apparent:

1) Work out how to generate a random number in JS (easy Googling)

2) Work out how to pick out a random element form an array using point 1

3) Realise that a nodeset, e.g. as the result of `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelectorAll` is array-like (but not actually an array), and so we can pick out a particular element of it via square-bracket syntax, as with arrays. We can therefore apply point 2 to this nodeset.

So:

```
var
spans = document.querySelectorAll('span'),
span = spans[Math.floor(Math.random() * spans.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work - random code I pulled from various searches but in theory you could put all your spans into a array, count the length, generate random number bsaed on that length and access it via indecies:

```
var numSpans $("#container span").size();
var optionTexts = [];

// populat our span array
$("#container span").each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()) });

var random = NumMath.floor(Math.random() * optionText.length);

var randomSpan = optionText[random];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give an integer id to your spans

```
<span id=1></span>
<span id=2></span>
...
<span id=100></span>
```

So, you just have to make a random number in between your ids. To generate a random integer between to numbers you can use this function:

```
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var randomID = getRandomInt(1, 100);
```

Then, with your random integer you can select the span like this:

```
document.getElementById(randomID)
```

If you are using jQuery you can change the background-color like this:

```
$("#" + randomID).css("background-color", {new_color})
```